# HTML5 template is not appearing in Chrome 44 ..?

Tags: javascript, html

Follow the guideline in http://jsfiddle.net/falafelsoftware/8fa8g/
I try to build full html page to reproduce html5 template behavior

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <template repeat="{{ items }}">
            <a href="{{ Link }}">
                <img src="{{ Image }}" />
            </a>
        </template>
        <form>
            <legend>Enter new details:
                <legend>
                    <input type="text" name="Link" value="http://www.polymer-project.org" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" name="Image" value="http://www.polymer-project.org/images/logos/lockup.svg" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var template = document.querySelector('template');
        template.model = {
            items: [{
                Link: 'http://falafel.com',
                Image: 'http://www.falafel.com/images/default-album/falafellogo.png'
            }]
        };

        var btnAdd = document.querySelector('[type="submit"]');
        btnAdd.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            //BIND FORM INPUTS AS NEW ITEM
            template.model.items.push({
                Link: document.querySelector('[name="Link"]').value,
                Image: document.querySelector('[name="Image"]').value,
            });

            //CLEAR FORM FOR NEXT ENTRY
            document.querySelector('form').reset();
        });
        </script>

    </body>
    <!--script src="https://togetherjs.com/togetherjs.js"></script-->

    </html>
```

But this code is running well in the jsfiddle but nothing happen im my html page.
Could someone give me the reason - why and how could I do to solve this problem.
Thank in Advance

(PS: I am using Google Chrome Version 44.0.2403.107 m (64-bit) in Win8.1)

Comment: What do you expect to happen? I can't see anything in that code that would have a visible effect.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it's because your `var template` is an array, not a single element.

Comment: You can click the jsfiddle link and see the logo of Polymer appears after button click. But it is not working for me in single html page Quetin.
All of code is copied directly from this link @ArturoTorresSánchez..

Comment: Usually, code is running in the Jsfiddle must be running well in single html page..I expect to see a Polymer logo after each click @Quentin..You can try above link..And I running this snip code in same browser..I really surprise..